# Why can't I change the height of AsyncImage in kotlin compose?

Tags: android, image, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to adjust the size of the AsyncImage, but no matter what I did, my codes are as follows. I am trying to adjust the size of AsyncImage as you can see below. Shouldn't it be as much as the part shown in blue part?

```
Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(Color.Blue)
            ) {
                AsyncImage(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(350.dp),
                    model = state.mainItems?.image,
                    contentDescription = null
                )

                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                ){
                      Text(text = "TITLE")
                      Text(text = "CATEGORY DATE")
                }
            }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the issue with height, it's very likely because of aspect ratio of image and default contentScale of `AsyncImage` which is

```
ContentScale.Fit
```

To be sure of this you can add border modifier to AsyncImage or check out layout inspector to see its bounds.